# NGINX reverse proxy - minimal hardware requirements

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hardware, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have created a Docker container from nginx:1.20.1 Docker image and deployed it on Ubuntu 20.0.4. I would like to use it as a reverse proxy with a medium amount of requests. I am using SSL. I expect no more than 1000 concurrent requests. As it is going to work with web pages of medium size, I do not expect big payloads. What are actually the optimal hardware requirements for the NGINX reverse proxy?

Comment: You're going to need to give more details, what does `medium amount of requests` mean, specifically?  In any case, there's a lot of things that may affect resource consumption, such as: the number of concurrent requests, is nginx doing response compression, are you using SSL, how large are payloads, what type of content is going across nginx, etc.

Comment: I edited the question with the responses to your suggestions. I hope that it helps in estimation.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than asking, it might be easier for you to run it on the most minimal hardware you have access to, and then profiling it with a tool like apache bench to see if it's sufficient for your needs.